React Query fetches data from backend but results undefined
I'm new to react and typescript, but I just finished a course. In the course I was able to access data in the same way I am trying to in my own project but I'm not able to display any data. My react query functions are fetching data because I can see the data response in react query devtools, but my data.results are undefined when I try to map them. Here is my code:
service/apiClient.ts (Service)
import axios, {AxiosRequestConfig} from "axios";

export interface FetchResponse<T> {
    count: number;
    results: T[];
}

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api',
})

class APIClient<T>{
    endpoint: string;

    constructor(endpoint: string){ 
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    getAll = (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
        return axiosInstance
        .get<FetchResponse<T>>(this.endpoint, config)
        .then(res=>res.data)
    }

    get = (id: number | string) => {
        return axiosInstance
        .get<T>(this.endpoint + '/' + id )
        .then(res => res.data)
    }
}

export default APIClient

hooks/useMaterials.ts (Hook)
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import ms from 'ms';
import Material from "../entities/Material";
import APIClient from "../services/apiClient";

const apiClient = new APIClient<Material>('/materials')

const useMaterials = () =>
    useQuery({
        queryKey: ['materials'],
        queryFn: apiClient.getAll,
        staleTime: ms('1m')
    })

    export default useMaterials

components/MaterialList.tsx (Component)
import {
  Spinner,
  Table,
  TableContainer,
  Tbody,
  Td,
  Th,
  Thead,
  Tr,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import useMaterials from "../hooks/useMaterials";

const MaterialList = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useMaterials();

  if (error) return null;
  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;

  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table variant="striped" colorScheme="#E43D12">
          <Thead>
            <Tr>
              <Th>Title</Th>
              <Th>Qty</Th>
              <Th>Action</Th>
            </Tr>
          </Thead>
          <Tbody>
            {data?.results?.map((material) => (
              <Tr key={material.id}>
                <Td>{material.title}</Td>
                <Td>{material.qty}</Td>
                <Td></Td>
              </Tr>
            ))}
          </Tbody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default MaterialList;

entities/Material.ts (Interface)
export default interface Material {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    slug: string;
    qty: number;
}

Lastly here is a screenshot of the response:

Console.log for {data}

Console.log for {data?.results}


I get Property 'map' does not exist on type 'FetchResponse<Material>'.ts(2339)

firstly there is (D)ata from server response, secondly, I think it's not difficult to add a few console.log() to check "res, res.data, then data of useMaterials, then data.results"

data.results is undefined but data has an array of objects

I think you found the answer you needed yourself.

I know this is probably something dumb I'm missing. But I still don't see how to fix it. I tried adding a type of Materials[] to my hook, but that didn't work either. As stated, I'm really new to this.

I don’t understand what you mean. You’ve already found that you need to use data instead of data.results. Is there any other problem?

I think it's a different issue: I just found this error in my compiler:
'MaterialList' cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its type '() => void | JSX.Element' is not a valid JSX element type.     Type '() => void | JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.       Type 'void | Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.         Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

I  don’t see anything that could cause this error in the code you shared. I suspect you might have changed something because void usually means you’re missing a return statement in your component.

Is English your native language, or do you speak it fluently? I'm asking because I can help with learning React. My main interest in this is improving my spoken English.

English is my native language...but I got the error fixed finally

Try to console
console.log({data, isLoading, error})

Check which properties are in data. If results exist, it should definitely map. Also see error if there is any error.
But first you have to check this
getAll = (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
    return axiosInstance
    .get<FetchResponse<T>>(this.endpoint, config)
    .then(res=>res.data)
}

And assign appropriate response type that return from response. And change type accordingly.

I was able to get it fixed with the help of comments and this answer. I changed my apiClient service to the following:
 .get<T[]>(this.endpoint)
